# Wrapper to send command output via email (like cron)

Tags: linux, email, cron, command-line-interface

I'm looking for a wrapper command (ideally in Python) which executes a given command and handles its output (STDERR/STDOUT) similar to cron:

- if there was no output (and return code 0), do nothing
- otherwise send an email with the output

I don't need the ability to connect to an external server, the system's mail command will be good enough (I'm using Linux).

I found [cronwrap](https://github.com/Doist/cronwrap) but its emails are too verbose. There is also [croncoat](https://github.com/MatthiasKauer/croncoat) but it *requires* an external SMTP server (which is not always an option for me).

Ideally there would be a wrapper like croncoat but with support for the `mail` command and with configurable email notifications so I don't have to tweak the source code.

(I assume this is a duplicate question but probably I just used the wrong search terms.)

Probably this is a

Answer (score 0):

Can you just place a shell script in `/etc/cron.d/`? Below is a sample (`man 5 crontab` for more info). The cron job will send an email containing what is in the `echo` statement.

If you want to craft your own email instead (with a subject), this would be best accomplished in `test_condition.sh` and make sure no output is seen by the `cron` daemon.

```
# run shell script every 15 minutes to test something
*/15 * * * *  root   /root/test_condition.sh || echo "Script exited with status 1"
```

The script `/root/test_condition.sh` (be sure to protect it with `chmod 0750` or similar)

```
#!/bin/sh
# do things... test cron by exiting with 1. Comment out the next line to test mail
exit 1

# otherwise exit with a 0 and handle the email from here. 
echo "I did some things. Things happened. Big things." | mail -s "Something happened" root@localhost
exit 0
```

Comment: Actually I'm launching a background job from a custom application. If there is output this should be sent to an email address so errors won't go unnoticed. (The idea is to move quickly, integration with monitoring infrastructure, task queues etc. will come later.) So there are no mechanisms from cron. I just want similar behavior to cron (without the scheduling aspect).